# C# picturebox brings up Red X

Tags: c#

I am trying to zoom a image. Here is my code. At times the Red X box comes up. Unable to resolve this. It would be great if anyone could help me with this.

```
 private void radbtnZoomIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                m_PresentAngle = 0;
                GC.Collect();
                Image OriginalImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(m_filepath);
                OriginalImg.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, m_intCurrPage);
                if (OriginalImg != null  && m_zoomInPresentPercent < 500)
                {
                    int zoomPercentRequired = 0;
                    if(m_zoomInPresentPercent >=100)
                    {
                        zoomPercentRequired = m_zoomInPresentPercent + 100;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        zoomPercentRequired = m_zoomInPresentPercent + 20;
                    }
                                        cbZoomPercentage.Text = zoomPercentRequired + "%";
                    double zoom = zoomPercentRequired / 100.0;
                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(OriginalImg, Convert.ToInt32(OriginalImg.Width * zoom), Convert.ToInt32(OriginalImg.Height * zoom));
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                    img = pictureBox1.Image;

                    m_zoomInPresentPercent = zoomPercentRequired;
                }
                if (!(m_zoomInCount > 5))
                {
                    m_zoomInCount++;
                }
                if(m_zoomOutCount >0)
                { 
                    m_zoomOutCount--;
                }
                GC.Collect();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    GC.Collect();
                    MessageBox.Show("The image is too small or too big to be zoomed. Loading the original Image");

                    DisposeImage();
                    RefreshImage(m_filepath, m_width, m_height);
                    GC.Collect();
                }
                catch(Exception exp)
                {
                    throw new Exception("From Zoom, " + exp.Message + " The Application needs to exit");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does it means 'At times'? Is it happening for any particular image

Comment: Why do you always read in the image from disk? Keep it until you are done with it! Also: GC.Collect is basically never needed; the GC works all by itself. (Plus: It won't collect stuff you haven't disposed of..(What is DisposeImage doing?)) But you really should find out more about the when of the error: Is it when you click fast or often?

Comment: @Microsoft DN - Zoom allows to zoom a picture upto 500%. some times the picture zooms to 200,300,400 without any issues. some times the same zoom at 200 or 300 or 400 brings up the red box. not with a particular image. unable to predict when this happens

Comment: @TaW If I do not use GC.Collect then very often it brings up the red box or even runs into exceptions like out of memory or parameter invalid etc. DisposeImage() sets the picturebox image to null

Comment: Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(OriginalImg, Convert.ToInt32(OriginalImg.Width * zoom), Convert.ToInt32(OriginalImg.Height * zoom)); Would like to know with what width and height the bmp can be created successfully without out of memory exception